# jquery calling function repeatedly with params results in maximum callstack exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make icon blink and I got the following html:

```
<button type="button" id="user-card-icon-headphones" class="user-card__button" disabled="" >
   <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" id="user-card-icon-phone" class="user-card__button" disabled="">
   <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
</button>
```

I am doing like so:

```
function blinkIcon(iconId){
   $('#' + iconId).find('i').delay(100).fadeTo(100,0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100,1, blinkIcon(iconId));
}

blinkIcon('user-card-icon-headphones');
```

but I get icon blick only once and after the error saying maximum callstack exceeded is shown. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: That's because you are calling your function inside your function. `.fadeTo(100,1, blinkIcon(iconId));` Add a stop condition for that like counter.

Comment: can I call a function inside a function with params?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You already calling functions inside your function and passing it parameters : `blinkIcon(iconId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `blinkIcon` immediately, you need to pass it as a function to the animation.

```js
function blinkIcon(iconId){
   $('#' + iconId).find('i')
   .delay(100).fadeTo(100,0.5)
   .delay(100).fadeTo(100,1, function() { blinkIcon(iconId); });
}

blinkIcon('user-card-icon-headphones');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="user-card-icon-headphones" class="user-card__button" disabled="" >
   <i class="fa fa-headphones">xxx</i>
</button>
<button type="button" id="user-card-icon-phone" class="user-card__button" disabled="">
   <i class="fa fa-phone">yyy</i>
</button>
```

Note that there is no way to stop the blinking, you might be better off with using `setInterval`.